# How to mark a sentence with an 'if' statement in my HTML table if no columns are selected upon page load?

Tags: html, if-statement

I would like to make an `if` condition for my website that would consist of marking a sentence if the condition is met. Knowing that I practice on table filters, I wanted to know how I could mark a sentence with an `if` if I ever did not select anything in the column that is to say by starting the page that it is marked no column `selected` (What is the best way?)

```
if(especes=false){
  "No trials found"
}
```

Comment: This is not possible with HTML. This is not a programming language.

Comment: Please share your attempts to resolve the problem